# How do I access an ebay item's id via javascript within the listing?

Tags: javascript, ebay-design-templates

We have a small javascript snippet which runs as part of our ebay item descriptions.  The snippet requires the ebay `item id`.

In testing I found that there is a variable, `ebayItemId`, which seems suitable.  However, if a user navigates directly to the item page (e.g. direct link) without navigating through other ebay pages first then the variable is not present.

How do I access the item id, or should I look to reading it from the DOM?

---

To elaborate a bit on the `ebayItemId` variable.  I tested by opening a new private browser and navigating directly to the item's page.  Interestingly it works as long as the item's page isn't the very first ebay page to be loaded--even with a forced full reload (Ctrl-F5).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about injecting code into a third party site that [no longer allows doing so](https://www.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-policies/javascript-policy?id=4247).

Comment: Javascript is still allowed, but only in limited use-cases.  I don't the details of this feature (it was 5 years and a couple jobs ago) but I suspect being able to determine the item id is still a valid use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Main reason it's failing in the case opening in a new browser is ebay's strange behaviour to render the item description of the first item page you visit *not* via iframe but directly uncached within their own DOM.

In this particular case those javascript variables are not preset so you can't access them.

A tiny workaround would be to read the item number / item ID directly from the item page itself (by using plain javascript). That's not a neat solution but should be working.

You can do e.g. like this to cover both scenarios:

```
var resolvedItemID = 
    typeof ebayItemID !== 'undefined' ? 
    ebayItemID : document.getElementById('descItemNumber') ? 
    document.getElementById('descItemNumber').innerText : null;

if(resolvedItemID) {
    ... your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the classic Ebay API? if so, I think you should check the documentation, there are lots of interesting functions you can use:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/index.html